# Is there a way to have typescript throw error when a key does not exist?

Tags: typescript

as an example

```
const { foo, bar, bruno } = lala(['foo', 'bar']);

function lala(keys: string[]) {
    return keys.reduce((withIds, key) => ({
        ...withIds,
        [key]: 'some-new-value'
    }), {} as Record<string, string>);
}
    
console.log(foo, bar, bruno); // some-new-value some-new-value undefined
```

I'm trying to make typescript (under VSCode) to wiggle the `bruno` variable, as it's not in the array

Is there a special trick / function for such action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer overlaps a lot with @captain-yossarian's but it's without the additional type definitions

```
const { foo, bar, bruno } = lala(['foo', 'bar'] as const);

function lala<K extends readonly string[]>(keys: K): Record<K[number], string> {
    return keys.reduce((withIds, key) => ({
        ...withIds,
        [key]: 'some-new-value'
    }), {} as Record<K[number], string>);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA3jAZiEAaGAjAhgJ3RnAVzBBgF8YBeGAGyzoAoBtAcmRBfRexxYF0YWCDFCQoASgDcAWABQcxMWBQAluFr0sAHgDSMAKYAPKPrAATYTn1Yz4GgE8Y0HCrABzJnwB8DANb77CAAuGB1xEIAlfVAcM10mMEIAWwx9HD50Z1c3L3g5GAKYKyhCHDAYf0CAOiszQmB9BgYAdxUoAAsASQt0SvEqXIY4fMLRqvHWju6IVBHRgqZKvhCWCBAk-QBaMH1mzYA3ekJ9FjnycXQ4CiEYKJi4nQTk1PTMqBd3Lyk5MjkgA)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do:

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;

type Values<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = T[number]

type Reduced<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = {
  [P in Values<T>]: string
}

function lala<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(keys: T) {
  return keys.reduce((withIds, key) => ({
    ...withIds,
    [key]: 'some-new-value'
  }), {} as Reduced<T>);
}

const result =  lala(arr); // Reduced<readonly ["foo", "bar"]>
const { foo, bar, bruno } = lala(arr); // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgGYhJgGhkwCNFMBdeCGUSKAbgCgmoBPABwFMYA1OADYBXLhAA8AFRhcAHlC5gAJjQBKXOIvAC2AQSRw2Y6AgCWYAOYA%20S6hgT0YIQFsSXBBRbtuMNYqHAuRUlpOQVlH3VNMG09BAMjKFMLa1sAbyYYDAAFGDM%20QRFxCUsKAC4YYzNzJgBfFmwhMGAoE3AYAUE4YNl5JVVIrV19Q0rkywAKAGsuNghyiQBKGHTMhC4oIQQwGGnZgDo1vwDx8YB3EygACwBJZSJdpZQbcZXMmD2P86vbiAIMt-QuzKxAgICcXAAtGAuKcIQA3ApcTD-GoLIipGrUCJHQKSSwLZh1Jh0aAwNYQIQCWBodqdcaIBAEmAAemZ2P8uLWGkGGAARLgQLyiLyyAheRRLMTwKTUjABURRQqEI0QDBMWgOh16UgmayQtxmoFpEgQAgWEA)

Answer (score 1):

A part of this can actually be done using template types:

```
function foo<ResultType, KeyType extends keyof ResultType>(keys: KeyType[]): ResultType {
    return keys.reduce((withIds, key) => ({
        ...withIds,
        [key]: 'some-new-value',
    }), {} as ResultType);
}

const {a, b, c} = foo(['a', 'b']);
```

i am not sure if VSCode will pick up the missing key though, since i don't think that this would throw the compiler off, as the generic doesn't actually know the result type (it's just interpolating what it does know, which is that keys a and b definitely exist).

It would work a lot better if you knew the interface beforehand, then you can do the following:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

function bar<T extends keyof MyInterface>(keys: T[]): MyInterface {
    return keys.reduce((withIds, key) => ({
        ...withIds,
        [key]: 'some-new-value',
    }), {} as MyInterface);
}

const {a, b, c} = bar(['a', 'b']);
```

which would raise an compiler error and would as such show up in VSCode

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
const { foo, bar, bruno } = lala(['foo', 'bar']);
//                ^^^^^ <--- Error here

function lala<KeyType extends string>(keys: KeyType[]) {
    return keys.reduce((withIds, key) => ({
        ...withIds,
        [key]: 'some-new-value',
    }), {} as Record<KeyType, any>);
}
    
console.log(foo, bar, bruno); // some-new-value some-new-value undefined
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA3jAZiEAaGAjAhgJ3RnAVzBBgF8YBeGAGyzoAoBtAcmRBfRexxYF0AlAG4AsAChxiYsCgBLcLXpYAPAGkApgE8AKpoAO6mOoAeUdWAAmEGNByywAcwB8DANZaIALhgad%209UyC8OIwoTA46lCEOGAw7poQAHQRFoTA6gwMAO6yUAAWAJJW6PECVE4wDHAhYbWJ9Tn5RRCoNbWhTPF83iwQIAC26gC0YOpZQwBu9ITqnG3kAuhwFFjWAErqoDgWalq6BuhYYJpOwuJk8%20KgkCA06ok0IA4M7Pi4%20EQkwjAA9D82A2Go3GUxoMwBgxGY0m00MxAs6kQ9nUFnEQA)